# Laravel Error on eager loading relations when migrated from 5.1 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, eager-loading

```
User.php 

namespace ESP;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable; 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword; 

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

use DB;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract 
{

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function companies(){
           return $this->belongsToMany('ESP\Company', 'company_user', 'user_id', 'company_id');
    }

   public function scopeUsername($query, $username){

    return $query->where('username', '=', $username);
   }
}


Company.php 

namespace ESP;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use DB;

class Company extends Model {

    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('ESP\User');
    }
}

LoginController.php

namespace ESP\Http\Controllers\Login;

use ESP\Http\Requests;

use ESP\Http\Controllers\Controller; use ESP\CustomClass\LDAP\adLDAP;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use ESP\LoginAttempts; 

use ESP\Helpers\UtilityHelper;

use ESP\User;

use DB; 

use Auth; 

use Session; 

use View; 

use Paginator; 

use DateTime; 

use Input;

class LoginController extends Controller 
{

    private function _authenticateClient($username, $password)
    {
        $g = User::with('companies')
            ->where( 'username', $username )
            ->where( 'password', md5( $password ) )
            ->get();
        dd($g);
    }
}
```

Error has something like this.

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::companies()
```

I can't even make use of the local scope Username on my controller call.

This models are working perfectly fine on my laravel 5.1. But im trying to migrate my codebase to 5.3 and im stuck with this issues.

Comment: Change (interfaces and traits) `User` model like here:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php

Comment: I already Changed the user model. im still getting the same error

Comment: namespace ESP;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User  extends Authenticatable
{
 protected $primaryKey = 'id';
 protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];
 protected $guarded = ['id'];
 protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
  public function companies(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('ESP\Company');
    }

 public function components(){
        return $this->belongsTo('ESP\Component');
    }  
}

Comment: The relationship declaration works perfectly ony my previous 5.1 installation. but now all functions declared are not working. even localscopes

Answer (score 0):

You can check app/config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\ESP\User::class,
    ]
],
```

make sure you registered your user model correctly.

Comment: Yes. i've checked it already. model is ESP\User::class since i have my app namespace aliased to ESP.

and as far as the model concerns. I havent used the AuthProvider for my authentication yet. it's just to fetch if there's any record from my user table eager loading the related company. But still throwing the exact same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried creating a new model Users and it works. Looks like the default User model is restricted. i cant access any custom methods i add in the default User model.